# When Smokesight is shared, whose magically created smoke can one see through?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, wizard

The wizard focused school [smoke](http://aonprd.com/SchoolDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Air) includes the Smokesight ability (emphasis mine):

> Smokesight (Su): You can see normally through natural fog and smoke, as well as **any fog and smoke that you (but not others) magically create**. A number of times per day equal to 3 + your Intelligence bonus, you can touch another creature as a standard action to grant it **this vision** for 1 hour.

In this case, is "this vision" referring to the ability to see through one's own magically created fog and smoke or the ability to see through the person with Smokesight's own fog and smoke?

As an example, suppose Alice is a wizard with this ability. When Alice shares "this vision" with Bob, does this mean that Bob can now see through fog and smoke magically created by Alice or through fog and smoke magically created by Bob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob can see through Alice's smoke and fog.

---

Although assuming designer intent may not always be great practice, in this instance I think it is safe to assume that the idea behind *Smokesight* is that a Smoke Wizard is granting their allies the ability to see through their own smoke and fog specifically because they are likely to be creating a lot of magical smoke/fog.

Having a Wizard that specializes in creating magical fog/smoke could be really annoying for the rest of the party if they require Line of Sight for their attacks and abilities to be effective (which is something that most attacks and abilities do require). Therefore, the way in which a Smoke Wizard makes themselves useful to the party rather than a hindrance is by granting their allies the ability to see through the smoke and fog that they will surely be generating.